# How should I handle an abandoned sink disposal circuit?

Tags: electrical

I recently removed my garbage disposal and replaced it with a regular P drain. However, I am now left with exposed wires that connected to the disposal from the house. How can I finish these up to make them safe? The breaker is off and can remain off indefinitely without impacting power to other appliances, but I can't get back into the box without removing my cabinets so that is not an option.

[image]

Comment: By "the box" are you referring to a local junction box or the service panel?

Comment: Presumably there's a switch controlling the disposal, likely in a box above the counter? Disconnect the wires and cap them there, the under-sink cable will no longer be "hot" or capable of becoming "hot" inadvertantly. Consider further dismantling/removal to remedy your illegal hidden junction box.

Comment: @kreemoweet Good question; may have been a magnetic switch in the stopper?  Would be good to know, and also to know where the inaccessible "box" is and how OP knows it's there.

Answer (score 28):

Don't remove the cable.  You or a future owner might want to put a disposal back there or use it for a dishwasher, hot water dispenser, or something else.

Install a metal junction box on the rear wall and install the cable into it correctly as if it was live and in use. Ground the box correctly but leave the other wires capped as you have there.  Then put a cover on the box and leave the circuit off.   If anyone needs an outlet there, all they have to do is buy one suitable for what they are installing and turn it back on.  Looks like #12 wire? Making it even more versatile in future.

Tape a note in the new junction box saying it is on a breaker #N and tape a note in the breaker panel saying circuit #N terminates in the junction box in the kitchen cabinet.

Comment: Love this answer, though I would use a marker to note the circuit instead of a note. Same idea though.

Comment: Label printers are the way. Much more legible than writing with your normal human hands. Mine gets abused for everything

Comment: If someone wants to post a question about the best way to leave notes in metal boxes, maybe then I'll break out a comment about my Hello Kitty label printer and papyrus style labels? 

Answer (score 7):

> but I can't get back into the box without removing my cabinets so that is not an option.

Wait.  You have a junction box you can't access???

That's a code violation. You're not allowed to bury junction boxes. They must be accessible at all times without disassembling any part of the building or damaging finish materials. Maintaining your electrical system is impossible without ability to access boxes.  It creates very costly "searched for hours and cannot find" type problems.

If you can cut holes in the back of cabinets to restore access, you'll need to do that... and either put up with the "ugly", or place a door or easily removed false back in there.   Your other alternative is to permanently abandon every circuit in that box, by destroying all wires which you can reach from the breaker panel to it, and from it to elsewhere.

As much as I like the idea of preserving the circuit run for future use, the accessibility problem needs to be resolved one way or the other. You decide between restoring access or destroying the circuit.

> The breaker is off and can remain off indefinitely without impacting power to other appliances.

That is not enough; anyone could turn it back on at any time.  Appliance repairman, other family member. People having electrical problems tend to throw every breaker in the panel to "see if that fixes it".  Code requires the wires be disconnected from the breaker and capped off, even if you aim to keep the circuit for future use.

The old breaker can remain in place; not allowed is pulling it and leaving a gaping hole in the panel face for curious fingers to explore. It's easier to leave it in place than hunt down a listed blank cover for that panel, and those tend to be flimsy anyway.